# Spring Framework: How can i configure and run spring framework project?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I downloaded spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE .

I have also downloaded eclipse-j2ee and intellijIDEA.

But can't understand how to configure and run spring framework project .

It will be nice if someone tell me the process to do it step by step .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear.  You should follow up if you have a specific issue; ie you tried something and you can't get it to work.  Include relevant configs and code. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-instantiation

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials to try from, just google for one. If you are stuck at a specific step, post a question on it.

Comment: Sorry, this one gets a downvote.  There are a ton of tutorials out there; this is not even really a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to download a [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) and create a simple project using Spring Template project wizard. There are also LOTS of interactive tutorials right from within Spring Tool Suite.

For example [here](http://www.dotkam.com/2010/04/06/spring-batch-quick-start/) is how to create a Spring Batch project using STS without writing any code at all.

Comment: I have downloaded Spring Tool Suite. But how can i create a spring project and run it with apache tomcat server ?

Comment: Creating a controller how can i pass the value to views ? How can i create views ?

Comment: "File" => "New" => "Spring Template Project". Choose "Spring MVC Project", enter project name, top level package ( e.g. org.guru.xyz ), click next. You have yourself a brand new "Spring MVC" project. In order to deploy it, right click on your project ( on the left hand side ), go to "Run As" => "Run On Server". This will deploy it to Tomcat for you, and will open a "http://localhost:8080/somemvc/" page where you would see "Hello world!". Take a look at "HomeController" class in order to start understanding how Controllers work.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are a lot of tutorials. Let's start from "hello world".

http://www.roseindia.net/spring/spring3/spring-3-hello-world.shtml